# Design principles for creating a domain-specific scientific library

Tags: scientific-computing

What are good principles in designing a software library for the use of scientists in a specific discipline? By this I mean areas such as chemistry, physics, materials science, microscopy, bioassays, astronomy, etc. I exclude generic libraries such as SciPy, R, Matlab, JAMA, etc. which cover a range of disciplines or are specifically mathematical or for data analysis. (Currently a number of us are involved in building open source libraries in chemistry and it would be valuable to know of experience from other domains).

I appreciate that this is an ambitious task and it is not easy to get funded but it is becoming increasingly important for reproducible and verifiable science.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It should allow its users--scientists--to do *science* in that domain instead of *programming*.  The less traction have purely programming concepts, as "handlers", "controllers", "pointers", "memory leaks" etc, the better it fits your end-users;
2. It should allow people, who find your lib interesting, to maintain it after you abandon it.  Shorter, it should not be developed as "throwaway code" or it should be  done in a "good" wat.  See [your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373980/good-strategies-for-developing-throwaway-code) on that matter.
3. To design an API an expert, who will *use* this library, should be involved.  He should know, what a usual problem-solving program requires from the library you're writing and define the main concepts you're to implement.  Design your API after what the expert says, not in the way you see it.  If you're the expert as well, then whatever, invite another guy, who's *not* involved in development.  The reason is that developers tend to design the API in the way *they* see natural, the way natural for the implementation.  Whereas it should be natural for problems it's involved into.

Answer (score 2):

"What are good principles in designing a software library for the use of scientists in a specific discipline?" - first and foremost is being a domain expert, IMO.  The kinds of packages that are usually successful in those areas are written by chemists, physicists, biologists, etc.

You have to ask yourself if it's easier for a scientist in one of those areas to learn programming or a programmer to learn a scientific discipline.

Judging by the number of books I see for learning language X in 21 days versus those claiming to confer mastery in chemistry, biology, or physics in the same time frame, I'd guess that scientists are more likely to program their own solutions.

Comment: Producing good software requires skills you won't find in "Learn Intercal in 21 Days".  Obviously you need a domain expert, and preferably access to several of them.  However, software a physicist writes will look like physicist-written software, and is likely to be less reliable than software written by a competent software professional.

Comment: I would submit that it's far easier for a physicist to learn how to write professional software than it'll be for a software professional to learn physics.  The fact that so many software developers come from other fields like physics suggests that it's far more probable that the physicist or engineer will write very good code.  Your "physicist-written software" will be far off the mark in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

Good to think about good general API design regardless of how domain-specific it is, so check out [this google tech talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aAb7hSCtvGw).  (Joshua Block)

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be: gauge the common programming skills of the scientific community you want to reach (most probably yours!) and develop something they can use (or that requires just a bit of learning, but not too much). Keep it simple, or hide the complexity in the deep internal parts. Scientists are not professional programmers.